# SQL another Normalization way

Tags: sql, database, normalization, erd

I just  try to do the task and stuck on normalization. ( This should be LOGICAL ERD )

[image]

Is it any more possible way for normalization up here?
I just stuck with it.
Sorry I just misses in group Members table the star near Group ID

[image]

Comment: Not sure whether Stack Overflow is the best possible Stack Exchange site for this; and whether you should normalise or not might depend on the problem(s) you're dealing with. Some things you could try: (1) group members, group leaders, and supervisors could be summarised as `Roles` assigned (N:N) to `Persons`; (2) some personal information could be moved to separate tables, e.g. `Addresses`. This might make sense e.g. when it's probably that some people live together.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about first one. When I will do it , how I then will connect this person table to three others? like how do I have to fill the person table with data that all others tables take right information?

Comment: Are `leader telephone number` `emergency contact number` and `current mobile number` always the same? Or can a emergency contact number differ from the regular phone number of the person?

Are individual members participating in a Activity, or is it always a group?

We would have to make a lot of assumptions if we were to decide if your model was correct.

Comment: not the tel number is not the same, individual participating in activity

Comment: Do you maybe have an example of the data that you are modeling this for? If so, could you add it to the question.

Comment: And for second table can some one explain how do I have to fill in information to makes it for ? for example for this example:
----------
-
Lists groups and the members belonging to each group.  For each group show the unique identifier and its name (if any).  For each member, show the unique identifier, the name, gender, date of birth and identifier of their group leader.  Within each group, sort members by surname and forename.

Comment: """""Do you maybe have an example of the data that you are modeling this for? If so, could you add it to the question."""""" I have some data, BUT i change this Logical ERD thousands of time so I I try to do ERD first before enter data again(((

Comment: I don't need data as it is entered in your new system, based on this ERD. I need data as it is used now, before implementing this ERD. Something like forms you fill in now to take part in these activities.

Comment: @JoyT Do you have Skype or any other way of communication?

Comment: @BredBomy to list all the members belonging to a `Group`: find all `Person`s such that there exists a `GroupMember` record with `group_id` equal to the `Group.id` and a `person_id` equal to `Person.id`.

Comment: ... there shouldn't be a line from Person to Activity (the relation goes through ActivityParticipant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroupMember, GroupLeader, and Supervisor should be relationships to a Person table. Perhaps something like the following?

```
Person (
    id
    name
    surname
    date of birth
    gender
    home address
    emergency contact number
    comment field
)

Activity (
    id
    type of activity
    activity description
    date
    morning or afternoon
    supervisor -> Person
)


ActivityParticipant (
    activity id -> Activity
    person id -> Person
)

Group (
    id
    name
    start date of stay
    end date of stay
    (amount of people in group?)
)

GroupMember (
    person id -> Person
    group id -> Group
)

Group Leader (
    group id -> Group
    person id -> Person
)

Chalet (
    id
    Chalet number
    Chalet name
    number it sleeps
    price per individual
)

Accomodation (
    group id -> Group
    chalet id -> Chalet
)
```

Comment: Do you mean need to create another table? called person ?

Comment: Yes, and then pull at least Name, (Surname?), and telephone number into it (those are the fields that are repeated, i.e. could be normalized).  It would be natural to put all the other person related fields in that table too.

Comment: Emmm, I understand that I'm not good in it but how I can put name, surname tel number and so on to one table and connect 3 tables to it IF they have different name..... I just can't get how i then should fill in the tables to makes it work.

Comment: @BredBomy edited my answer to reflect normalizations and relationships.

Comment: -> mean primary key is it right?

Comment: -> is the foreign key (to the primary key of another table). I've also modeled the relationships as many-to-many when they perhaps do not need to be (not enough information).

Comment: should we count(GroupMember.person id) easily rather having a field  Group.amount of people in group

Comment: Can you explain this bit?? supervisor -> Person

Comment: supervisor is a foreign key on activity that points to the primary key (id) of Person. In sql it would be something like `supervisor int foreign key references Person(id);`

Comment: @TonyShih yes, that's why I put it in parenthesis (on the other hand it might be a worthwhile denormalization, but that's neither here nor there ;-)

Comment: If you can, can you show me how do I have to display like this question???------------------Lists groups and the members belonging to each group. For each group show the unique identifier and its name (if any). For each member, show the unique identifier, the name, gender, date of birth and identifier of their group leader. Within each group, sort members by surname and forename.

Comment: As another example like this??------Lists groups and the members belonging to each group.  For each group show the unique identifier and its name.  For each member, show the unique identifier, the name, gender, date of birth and identifier of their group leader.

Answer (score 0):

> Relational databases don't support inheritance

Three possible ways I know off how to solve this problem are:

[1.Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

[2.Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) (This is a bit like @thebjorn is suggesting.)

[3.Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) (This is what you have now, I don't see any problem using this solution.)

**EDIT:**

I see you changed it to `LOGICAL ERD`, this was of course about the physical model.

Comment: So I did wrong for logical ERD????

Comment: No, it's your own decision if you want a logical or physical ERD. I meant that the solutions in my post are applied when you change your logical model to a physical one. It is not uncommon to have inheritance in your logical model.

Comment: I need logical ERD, so I guess it's is  right for logical one ?